# abstract Algebra (group theory)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Three coins are placed on a table; showing heads. Can you get all the coins to show tails, by turning over two coins at a time? Use Group Theory to prove your answer.

I know that the answer is no I cannot get all coins to show tails however I  have no idea how to put it in terms of group theory. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all the solutions guys. I may understand them further in the course. But currently our teacher only gave use the basic about groups and subgroups to solve the problem. We are not expected to use homomorphism and stabilizer theorems etc.

Comment: In that case, it's (even) hard(er) to tell what is really meant by “use group theory”... but maybe the “alternately” part of my answer will suit you?

Answer (score 2):

You insist on using group theory to hide the parity check, so here it is.

In group-theoretic terms the situation is as follows: we have the group $G={\bf Z}_2^3$, and the subgroup $\langle(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\rangle=H\leq G$, and we ask if $(1,1,1)\in H$.

The answer is no: consider the homomorphism $f\colon G\to {\bf Z}_2$ defined by $f(a,b,c)=a+b+c$. Clearly $H$ is contained in the kernel, while $(1,1,1)$ isn't, so $(1,1,1)\notin H$.

Alternately, you could just compose the generators of $H$ in all possible ways to see that actually $H=\{(0,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$, though this method doesn't generalise to a larger number of coins quite so well.

Comment: Wait a minute! Why you didn't get a downvote ?!?

Comment: What is the Z with the 3 and 2. What does the 3 and 2 represent

Comment: @user159519: ${\bf Z}_2$ is the two-element group, while ${\bf Z}_2^3$ is its third power.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use group theory for this problem, but if you insist, you could represent the current state of the three coins by a bit string of length 3, i.e. as an element of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$, where a 1 bit represents a tail and a 0 bit represents heads. The initial state is $(0,0,0)$. Flipping two coins amounts to adding to the current state one of $(1,1,0), (0,1,1)$ or $(1,0,1)$, where the addition is performed in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Thus, when two coins are flipped, the sum of the three bits stays even.  Thus the number of 1's (i.e., number of tails) will always stay even.

Comment: Don't dare not using group theory again! :) (I was not the downvoter, btw)

Comment: @AndreaMori Of course! But still, it's clear this problem is easily solved using the parity argument, and parity can be cast in the language of the group of order 2.  I just want to make the poster aware of that. (I always like to see multiple proofs for a problem though, and my recasting in terms of groups is just a rewording, and I would like to see something more nontrivial than that in terms of how group theory can be used for this problem).

Comment: What does the 3 and 2 in the Z represent?

Comment: @user159519: In general, the set of all $n$-bit strings is exactly the set $\{0,1\}^n$, which (with the operation of binary addition) is the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \cdots \mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2^n$.

Answer (score -3):

Group theory has nothing to do with this, it's a simple parity check.

There are three possibilities at each step:

- you turn two heads into two tails: number of heads drops by 2, number of tails goes up by 2.
- you turn two tails into two heads: number of tails drops by 2, number of heads goes up by 2.
- you turn a head into a tail and a tail into a head: number of heads and tails is unchanged.

Since the numbers change by leaps of 2, if you start with an odd number of tails, you still have an odd number of tails after any whatsoever sequence of changes as before.

Obviously this applies to any odd numbered set of coins you decide to start with.

Comment: Parity check has everything to do with group theory!!! You're looking at the sign of the transposition, and the number of elements not dividing the order of the operation. As a question of applying group theory to examples that can be solved in other ways, this is a good one.

Comment: @Mathmo123: I'm not sure that this is a good example. You can easily explain the elementary parity check approach to any bright 10 years old kid, while I don't think you'd be as successful using group theory.

Comment: I completely agree that group theory isn't the best way to solve this question. However, the asker specifically asked for a group theoretic answer. This kind of question often comes up when learning group theory for the first time, as it is a good exercise in seeing what's really going on here - the point is that we have a group of operations of order 2 (swap coins) that is acting transitively on a set of three coins.

Comment: I also took offence to the erroneous assertion that "Group theory has nothing to do with this". How else do we think about associative actions acting on a set??

Comment: @Mathmo123: You took offence ????? Wow! :)

Comment: Took offence in a British sense of "was slightly surprised" :)